# How can I send an Alert Dialog as a push notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alertdialog

I would implement a push notification, but this push notification wouldn't simply be a notification on the status bar, but a **dialog**. Kind of like this:

[image: Android Notification Action buttons]

I'm starting with Android development and couldn't figure it out.
I'm sending the notification via NodeJS and I'm not sure if the payload is right too.